# How do I show that a parametric equation intersects the directrix?

Tags: conic-sections

The question was:

The points P and Q on the curve: $$x = 2at, y= at^2$$ have parameters p and q respectively.
Show that PQ intersects the directrix at: $$ \left (\frac{2a(pq-1)}{p+q},-a  \right ) $$

I've managed to find that the equation of the chord PQ is:
$$ y - \frac{1}{2} (p+q)x+apq=0 $$
but after this I'm a bit confused has to how to find the directrix using a parametric equation.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. +1 for showing us what you know. Please continue to do the same. Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're there. To proceed, here's a hint.

**Hint**

This is a standard parabola given by $x^2=4ay$ and its directrix is at $y=-a$. So,

> to solve for the point of intersection $PQ$ with $y=-a$ is to just plug in $y=-a$ and solve  the resulting linear equation in $x$ (for $x$, of course.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I now understand how to find the equation of the directrix.